# What is the difference between wine(x86) and wine(amd64)?

Tags: 14.04, wine, playonlinux

I installed **Wine 1.7.13** from **PlayOnLinux** to run Origin client on my Ubuntu 14.04. But the menu shows two tabs with **Wine(x86)** versions and **Wine(amd64)** versions.

Can anyone explain the difference between the two?

Which version is more reliable for gaming?

Comment: As with anything related to this: amd64 is 64-bit and x86 is 32-bit. "Which version is more reliable for gaming? " Depends on the game...

Comment: I'm trying to run FIFA14 on my Ubuntu but am not optimistic of my chances. Which version should i go for then?

Comment: @SY13: Ramvignesh's answer is better if he just edits it and adds "32-bit or 64-bit game?"  You *can* unaccept the bad one and "accept" the better one!  ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Can anyone explain the difference between the two?**

> x86 denotes 32-bit machine architecture.
>
> amd64 denotes 64-bit machine architecture.

**Which version is more reliable for gaming?**

> Depends.
>
> x86 is reliable for 32-bit games.
>
> amd64 is reliable for 64-bit games.

**Postscript:**

> amd64 is commonly referred to as x64. The previously used 64-bit version was designed by the Intel corp which was called as x86-64. It was not compatible with the native x86 instruction set. In 2003, AMD introduced the perfect 64-bit version for the x86 instruction set. Since they introduced it, it is named after them as amd64. Hope you would have enjoyed the history :)

Comment: Good one!  Sometimes it's better to down-vote an existing bad answer and write a new one then to try to edit it!  At least you've got an up-vote from me now!  ;-)

Comment: thank you. n ur comment deserves many votes. i've made one too :-)

Comment: Just do me a favour and read http://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc

Comment: If only i could, dont have enough rep!! I'm a noob!! :P

Comment: Oh, and I forgot to add: It's considered "polite" to leave a comment when you downvote!

Answer (score 0):

Because AMD was the first to develop a 64-bit processor, we still call a 64-bit version "AMD64" today although there are more Intel 64-bit processors today then AMD ones.

"x86" is for 32 bit machines only.

So which is "more reliable for gaming", depends on the game: 32 bit or 64-bit?

Answer (score 0):

- Wine x86 will **ONLY** run 32 bits programs.
- Wine x64 will **ONLY** run 64 bits programs.

Most of x64 programs come with x32 version, so, for better compatibility you may preffer it.